# NETDOM with powershell FOREACH: Mass computer re-naming from CSV

Tags: variables, powershell, csv, foreach

NETDOM is a Microsoft command-line utility that allows you to rename and/or join a remote computer to a domain/workgroup.

The command looks like this

```
NETDOM.exe /RENAMECOMPUTER:Abot /newname:NewA /userD:DomainAdmin /passwordD:password /userO:LocalAdmin /passwordO:password /force /reboot:30
```

I made a CSV of computer names. in Column 1 is the "OLD-Computername" in Column 2 is the "NEW-Computername". It looks like this

[image]

I want to use a Powershell "FOREACH" loop to replace the $OldName and $NewName values with the "Old Name" and "New Name" values found in the CSV.

```
FOREACH (I don't know what to put here) {
    NETDOM.exe /RENAMECOMPUTER:$OldName /newname:$NewName /userD:DomainAdmin /passwordD:password /userO:LocalAdmin /passwordO:password /force /reboot:30
}
```

I have only used FOREACH with a temp variable FOREACH ($temp in $something). Is it possible to use more than 1?

Comment: I recommend looking at `Import-Csv` and `Foreach-Object`.

Comment: PowerShell has this amazing cmdlet called `Get-Help` that will explain how things like `ForEach` are used. Also, you're working with a CSV file, and want to get it's info into PowerShell, you want to "Import" the info, so there's another cmdlet called `Get-Command` that you can run to find all the cmdlets that will let you import data. `Get-Help` can help you figure out how to use `Get-Command` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Import-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx) for importing a CSV. Use [`Rename-Computer`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849792.aspx) instead of `netdom` for renaming a computer. Use [`Get-Credential`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849815.aspx) to prompt for credentials.

```
$domainAdmin = Get-Credential -Message 'Domain Admin'
$localAdmin  = Get-Credential -Message 'Local Admin'

Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' | ForEach-Object {
  Rename-Computer -NewName $_.'New Name' -Computer $_.'Old Name' -DomainCredential $domainAdmin -LocalCredential $localAdmin -Restart -Force
}
```

Use [`Get-Help`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849696.aspx) to get further information.

Comment: this is very similar to the script found here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2243.how-to-rename-computers-using-powershell-and-a-csv-file.aspx

Comment: @Blake Not very surprising, since it's how you do this kind of thing. `Rename-Computer` (PowerShell v3 and newer) is more PoSh than `netdom`, though.

Comment: I was able to get this working with the Rename-Computer command. NETDOM works too, but I like Rename-Computer better because NETDOM is only included in Windows Server installations. "Rename-Computer" seems to work even if executed from a windows 7 box.