# Rename/unjoin a computer from a domain, that isn't on the domain

Tags: powershell, workflow

Working on a script that will be run on a clone of a VM.  When cloned out, the IP settings switch from static to DHCP and the name/domain remain the same as the source.  Parts of my script require that the VM be on the domain to run, however, I can't just set an open IP on the NIC, since it will then  update DNS with the new IP, disable the computer object in AD and break the trust relationship.

Normally, through windows, I join a workgroup [remove from domain] and the OS is happy, just wants a reboot. I can then set the IP on the NIC, change the name and set it to join back to the domain before another reboot. I then have 2 of the same machine, different names and IP addresses without any conflicts.

I am at an impasse at getting this accomplished with PowerShell though. I can't rename or join a workgroup unless I am on the domain. I thought workflows would be the answer, but after reading a little bit on it, I am not so sure anymore.

So this is more of a workflow Q than actual code and any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

wmi commandline works and gives me a starting point.

```
@echo off
start /B /W wmic.exe /interactive:off ComputerSystem Where "Name='%computername%'" Call UnJoinDomainOrWorkgroup FUnjoinOptions=0
start /B /W wmic.exe /interactive:off ComputerSystem Where "Name='%computername%'" Call JoinDomainOrWorkgroup name="WORKGROUP"
start /B /W wmic.exe /interactive:off ComputerSystem Where "Name='%computername%'" Call Rename name="standaloneComputer"
shutdown.exe /r /t 0 /f
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following procedure when dealing with cloned Windows VMs:

1. Start the clone with disconnected network interface(s).
2. [Remove non-present network adapters](https://superuser.com/a/470958).
3. [Assign new IP address(es)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/02/28/use-powershell-to-configure-static-ip-and-dns-settings.aspx) to the remaining network adapter(s).

   ```
   $wmi = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled='true'"
   $wmi.EnableStatic('192.168.23.42', '255.255.255.0')
   $wmi.SetGateways('192.168.23.1', 1)
   $wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(('192.168.23.13', '192.168.23.14'))
   ```
4. [Rename the computer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31178979/1630171) and remove it from the domain.
5. Reboot.
6. Reconnect the interface(s).
7. Join the renamed computer back to the domain.

**Note:** Make sure the clone has a local admin account that you can log in with while the domain is not accessible.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar.  The problem with this is, I clone into the same domain as the source, then it will have the IP/name of the source. NIC will be enabled, but vSphere auto sets it to DHCP, which is fine. If I assign this to a new IP, it will basically knock the source server off the domain.  So I have to unjoin the domain, but I cant do that unless I am connected to the domain [unlike when you can with windows GUI].  calling WMIC though allows me to unjoin the domain and rename the computer without having access to the domain/computer object.